# PHP , How I can receive connected db from another file for throw to each function

Tags: php

I have 2 file(Class), connect_db.php and  manage.php, I want to pull db connected link from Connect_db class to Manage Class
but now I still put the same connected receiving in every function so I want to put only one time in this class and throw to
use for each function. I heard the Getter and Setter concept but I never use and not sure it be suitable for
this case.

```
<?php

//**connect_db.php**

class connect_db
{
  public function connect_db()
  {
      $link = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=net_pracharat","root","");
      $link -> exec("set names utf8");

      return $link;
  }
}  

?>




<?php
//**mange_db.php**

include("connect_db.php");

class mange
{

  //How I can do set here and send to each function

   public function view_process()
   {

      $link1 = new connect_db(); //**************************
      $link = $link1 -> connect_db(); //**************************
      //$link = $this->connect_db();

      $test_view = $link->prepare("SELECT *
                                   FROM tbl_province");
        $test_view -> execute();
        $result = $test_view->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
   }



   public function add_process()
   {
      $link1 = new connect_db(); //**************************
      $link = $link1 -> connect_db(); //**************************

      /*
        Process
      */

   }

   public function edit_process()
   {

      $link1 = new connect_db(); //**************************
      $link = $link1 -> connect_db(); //**************************

      /*
        Process
      */

   }

   public function delete_process()
   {
      $link1 = new connect_db(); //**************************
      $link = $link1 -> connect_db(); //**************************

      /*
        Process
      */
   }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many options.

1. Initialization in the constructor

```
class mange {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $connnect = new connect_db();
        $this->db = $connnect->connect_db();
    }

    public function view_process() {
        $this->db->prepare();
    }

}
```

2. The transfer by the setter

```
class mange {

    private $db;

    public function setDb($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function view_process() {
        $this->db->prepare();
    }

}
```

3. My favorite: Initialization of a static method in the constructor

```
class connect {

    public static function connect_db() {
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=net_pracharat", "root", "");
        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link;
    }

}

class mange {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = connect::connect_db();
    }

    public function view_process() {
        $this->db->prepare();
    }

}
```

Of course, you can otherwise initiate a static variable:

```
class connect {

    static $db;

    public static function connect_db() {
        if (!self::$db) {
            $link = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=net_pracharat", "root", "");
            $link->exec("set names utf8");
            self::$db = $link;
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

}
```

Look: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c5e33dc6f31dcaf27b34675c00749893eaebe24